# Chrome拡張機能開発(Extension)でonRequestFinished使用時にtargetDate.getTime is not a function

Tags: chrome-extension

Chrome拡張機能開発(Extension)にて、
`chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener` でHTTPリクエストを監視する際に、
一部のページでエラーが発生します。

```
chrome.devtools.network.onRequestFinished.addListener((data) => {
})
```

上記のように `onRequestFinished` を使用し、developer toolでリクエスト情報を取得しようとしたところ、

```
inspector.js:956 TypeError: targetDate.getTime is not a function TypeError: 
targetDate.getTime is not a function
    at SDK.Cookie.expiresDate (inspector.js:3603)
    at NetworkLog.HAREntry._buildCookie (inspector.js:6023)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at NetworkLog.HAREntry._buildCookies (inspector.js:6022)
    at NetworkLog.HAREntry._buildResponse (inspector.js:6009)
    at NetworkLog.HAREntry.build (inspector.js:6003)
    at Extensions.ExtensionServer._notifyRequestFinished (inspector.js:7414)
    at SDK.NetworkManager.dispatchEventToListeners (inspector.js:482)
    at SDK.NetworkDispatcher._finishNetworkRequest (inspector.js:5671)
    at SDK.NetworkDispatcher.loadingFinished (inspector.js:5644)
```

と表示されました。

エラーが出る場合と出ない場合があり、
双方を比較してみたところ、
Set-Cookieが使われているページだとエラーが出てデータが取得できませんでした。

これはChromeの設定によるものでしょうか、それともバグでしょうか。

OS: Windows 7
Chrome: 65.0.3325.181（Official Build） （64 ビット）

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Chrome のバグです。

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=801306

Comment: ありがとうございます。forumを追いかけてみます。

Answer (score -3):

なぜ気付かないのか・・・困ったもんです。[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]